# Calling Cpanel UAPI method

Tags: cpanel

i have the following simple script to list the ftp accounts
 but i am unable to get it to work as i have the following error as soon as it tries to call the constructor

```
 include '/usr/local/cpanel/php/cpanel.php';
$cpanel = new CPANEL(); // Connect to cPanel - only do this once.

// List FTP account information.
$list_ftp_accts = $cpanel->uapi('Ftp', 'list_ftp');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($list_ftp_accts);
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'There
>   was a problem fetching the env variable containing the path to the
>   socket' in /usr/local/cpanel/php/cpanel.php:146 Stack trace: #0
>   /public_html/uapi.php(4): CPANEL->__construct() #1
>   {main} thrown in /usr/local/cpanel/php/cpanel.php on line 146

Line 146 in cpanel.php

```
$socketfile = getenv('CPANEL_PHPCONNECT_SOCKET');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [a post on the cPanel forums](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/livephp-api-call-from-domain.257091/#post-1070922), you can only use LiveAPI from within cPanel's document root, meaning your code would need to be in either `/usr/local/cpanel/base/frontend/` or `/usr/local/cpanel/base/3rdparty/`. I ran into this while trying to use it in a WHM plugin (which would reside in `/usr/local/cpanel/whostmgr/docroot/`), and apparently that causes the same problem. If you're trying to run this from within cPanel or WHM, [this page](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/Guide+to+Testing+Custom+Code) has some debugging steps you can try walking through.

If you're trying to run this code on a different server or from within a normal website's hosting account, you'll definitely need to use a different interface, such as the XML or JSON API. These are unfortunately somewhat confusingly documented, but the [Guide to WHM API 1](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/Guide+to+WHM+API+1) page should get you started.

Answer (score -1):

Me too got the same error.

Try changing your file extension to `your_file.live.php`, instead of `your_file.php`. It solved the issue for me.

Referred the documentation [here](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/DD/Tutorial+-+Create+a+New+Paper+Lantern+Interface+in+PHP).

Comment: Nope, got exactly the same error as before: "There was a problem fetching the env variable containing the path to the socket bla bla bla"